# Problem with uploading multiple files PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

On my site I have a page where users can upload files to go with the news post they're adding. I allow them to upload one image and one sound file. They don't have to add files if they don't want to, or they can just add one if they want. Problem I'm having is that my script only works if the user selects both files. If they choose none, or only one, then the script spits out 'Invalid File' as it can't find a file where one hasn't been selected.

I tried using:

```
if (isset($_FILES['filetoupload1'])) { 
    if (($_FILES["filetoupload1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["filetoupload1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["filetoupload1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["filetoupload1"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["filetoupload1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    ) {
        if ($_FILES["filetoupload1"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["filetoupload1"]["error"] . "<br />";
        } else {
        if (file_exists("media/" . $_FILES["filetoupload1"]["name"])) {
                echo $_FILES["filetoupload1"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            move_uploaded_file(
                $_FILES["filetoupload1"]["tmp_name"],
                "media/" . $_FILES["filetoupload1"]["name"]
            );
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
}


if (isset($_FILES['filetoupload2'])) { 
    if ($_FILES["filetoupload2"]["type"] == "audio/mp3") {
        if ($_FILES["filetoupload2"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["filetoupload2"]["error"] . "<br />";
        } else {
        if (file_exists("media/" . $_FILES["filetoupload2"]["name"])) {
                echo $_FILES["filetoupload2"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            move_uploaded_file(
                $_FILES["filetoupload2"]["tmp_name"],
                "media/" . $_FILES["filetoupload2"]["name"]
            );
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
}
```

and then

`if((isset($_FILES['filetoupload1'])) && (isset($_FILES['filetoupload2']))) { }`

before both first and second upload scripts if the user had selected both image and audio file. In other words it did this:

```
if filetoupload1 isset then run upload script that filters images.
if filetoupload2 isset then run upload script that filters audio.
if filetoupload1 AND filetoupload2 isset then run both upload scripts.
```

I have it set like that. The above should allow for all combinations of file uploads. right? but it doesnt work so..

Now I have no idea what to do. Here's the upload script for the audio, the image one is pretty much the same:

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "does not work". Output, expected results, real results, etc.

Comment: I get the error: Invalid file.
if neither of the files are selected, I get two 'Invalid file' errors.

it only works if both files have been selected. but I want the users to be able to choose what they upload with their news post as they may not always have a sound clip, or an image, or either, to go with their news post.

Comment: you have else echo invalid file if file is not uploaded. it is logical if you are getting invalid file two times if none are uploaded. your code permits what you want to achieve. just remove the echos or do something in its place if you wish.

Comment: sorry you're right. i was just being completey retarded. cant believe i spent the last hour or two staring at that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I get the error: Invalid file"

This is correct, since your code just does this.
Do not check if the file is set but if i.e. `$_FILES["filetoupload1"]["type"]` is not empty.

Comment: I dont think you understood me. or i didn't understand you. i made edits to my question to make it clearer

Comment: The new source code you posted actually helps to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

Your script makes your server vulnerable to a malicious user being able stomp on any file the webserver has access to:

```
$_FILES[...]['name'] - user supplied
$_FILES[...]['type'] - user supplied
```

You're trusting that the client has supplied the proper MIME type for the file, but nothing stops someone from forging a request and uploading "virus.exe" and setting the mime type to 'image/jpeg'. As well, since the remote filename is under user control, it can be subverted with malicious data. Consider:

```
$_FILES['picture']['type'] = 'image/gif'
$_FILES['picture']['name'] = 'remote_server_control.php'
```

Completely legitimate according to your script, because the mime type is "right", and yet you've now put a user-supplied PHP script on your server and with that they can take total control of your site and/or server.

Never EVER trust the data in the `$_FILES` array. Always determine MIME types via server-side utilities. If the script is only supposed to handle images, then use `getimagesize()`. As well, never use user-supplied filenames. Use something determined server-side to give the file a name, like a databasde auto_increment ID number. Even though your code doesn't allow for overwriting existing files, it's trivial to just come up with a new name and boom... new version of the remote takeover script.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to add a hidden text, this hidden will check witch upload fields are active, you make this check with javascript:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

 </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadForm()
{
var size = 0;
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["upload1"].value.length;
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["upload2"].value.length;
if (x > 0)
  {
  size = 3;
  }
if (y > 0)
 {
  size += 2;
 }
 return size;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>


<form name="myForm" action="" method="GET" onsubmit="chose.value = uploadForm()">
<input type="file" name="upload1"><br>
<input type="file" name="upload2"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="chose" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Now, when you receive the form, you have to check the value of chose filed, if its 2, that is mean the image field is not empty, 3 audio filed is not empty, 5 both not empty:

```
<?php
switch($_GET["chose"])
 {
case 2:
//
 break;
case 3;
//
break;
case 5:
//
break;
default:
// here the user doesn't use any field

}
?>
```

Comment: I thought that this would have worked but the switches aren't getting triggered. I have triple checked the code as well. The only bit I dont understand is the javascript. How does that javascript code put a value in the address string to be able to $_GET it?

Comment: We check upload1 filed length, if its greater then 0, this mean a user put some thing, so here we add 2 to size variable, the same thing applied to the second filed except we here add 3.
When the form is submitted we execute the function witch will return either 0,2,3, or 5, depend in what user use(s) filed(s) or it doesn't at all, this value will be assigned to chose hidden filed and sent it with the form, in the server side, we check the value of chose and we decide depend in what it have value, I hope you understand me, I am sorry because I am not english native speaker..